# Run python script in folder with password (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, passwords

I was wondering who can I run a python script (.py) at start up if this script is located in a folder with password. 
The goal is run an script and not allow the access to the file. (read, write, copy...)

Thanks

Comment: Python is an interpreted language to run it you need read access to the file.

Comment: Then how could I solve my problem? I need privacy for the contents of the file.